# regex to match number math operand and number

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the best way to write a regex that matches a number, math operand, and then a number.

Not so fast, the numbers and the operands can be the symbol, e.g. ( 1, or + ) or the natural language strings ( one, plus, and ).

So it has to match one of the following:

- `0` or `1` or `2` or `3` or `4` or `5` or `6` or `7` or `8` or `one` or `two` or `three` or `four` or `five` or `six` or `seven` or `eight` or `nine` or `ten` or `eleven` or `twelve` or `thirteen`

Then one of the following:

- `+` or `-` or `*` or `x` or `X` or `/` or `^` or `plus` or `and` or `minus` or `added to` or `negative` or `positive` or `times` or `multiply` or `multiplied by`or `divided by` or `over` or `to the power of` or `raised to` or `raised to the`

and then one of the following:

- `0` or `1` or `2` or `3` or `4` or `5` or `6` or `7` or `8` or `one` or `two` or `three` or `four` or `five` or `six` or `seven` or `eight` or `nine` or `ten` or `eleven` or `twelve` or `thirteen`

Here are some examples:

- `2+2` will match
- `two-     2` will match
- `five raised to the     6` will match
- `2 2 minus 5 will match` ( because of the 2 minus 5 not because of the 2 2 minus )
- `2 2 /` will not match
- `8 -` will not match
- `0` will not match
- `five hundred forty-three plus 2` will match ( because of the forty - three or the three plus 2 )

I don't know how to do look aheads, but how I thought of doing this was: `/\d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen look ahead +|-|*|/|+ -|- -|plus\s+negative|plus\s+minus|positive\s+negative|minus\s+negative|negative\s+negative||minus minus|negative|positive|times|multiply|multipled\s+by|added\s+to|plus|minus|to\s+the\s+ power\s+of|times|multiply|multiplied\s+by|divided\s+by|over|raised\s+to|raised\s+to\s+the look ahead \d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen/g`

Comment: Don't waste your time with regexes. They cannot parse grammars. Use a parser: http://pegjs.majda.cz/, http://zaach.github.io/jison/

Comment: @georg please post that as an answer.

Comment: when i was learning i used to write my regexes, but then i had to troubleshoot them as there was always something wrong...which then took more time. Eventually i found out open source regexes are the best path to go as even though i spent a month learning and mastering, i am back to page 1..can't recall all patterns. Maybe if you use regex everyday then you should consider mastering it, but for most part it's easier to copy then to relearn it.

Comment: @user3743069: for what purpose? It's not going to be useful to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are for string pattern matching, not for parsing full grammars. Either use a grammar parsing library, or write your own by creating a grammar-accepting DFA and then running through your string as a character stream (which you can easily do because strings in JS act like arrays for the purposes of iteration).

Although I'd be remiss to not raise the "why would you accept textual input" question, because that's just being silly. It's not like keyboards don't let you type numbers and symbols.

Comment: I know keyboards can let you type both but I was thinking of alternative input methods.

Comment: why would those input methods generate full words instead of still just the numbers and operators?

Comment: It is complicated. It is just that there was potential for it to happen and I wanted to be safe each way.